# Phishing emails are learning what I send?

Tags: email-spam, phishing

I'm  getting a lot of Phishing emails very similar to the emails from companies I use.

Some of these companies and the emails we exchange are very unique. How would these malicious emails 'learn' the type of emails and content I send?

Could they be sniffing out content if so whats the recommended steps to prevent?

Comment: This might be a much better fit for security.se. Be sure to check their question guidelines first.

Comment: @TimCastelijns isn't that for information security

Comment: isn't that what your question is about?